# Do I need to read City of the Damned before Kinslayer?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, gotrek-felix

[City of the Damned](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Warhammer/gotrek-and-felix-city-of-the-damned-ebook.html) takes place before [Kinslayer](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Warhammer/gotrek-felix-kinslayer-hardback.html) and they were written by the same author, but I've read some [bad reviews](http://thefoundingfields.com/2014/03/gotrek-and-felix-city-of-the-damned-by-david-guymer-book-review-bellarius/) of City of the Damned, so I'm considering skipping it.

Do I need to read City of the Damned before starting The End Times and Kinslayer?

Is there any link between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked my good friend [David Guymer](https://twitter.com/WarlordGuymer/status/625938520377585664) (Author of CotD, The End Times and Kinslayer) to answer this for you:

> **Q.** *Quick question; Do I need to read City of the Damned before starting The End Times and Kinslayer?*
>
> **A.** *Quick answer - No :) Quick-ish answer, no but there are a few characters from CoTD that reappear in Slayer*

Comment: I guess that's about as canon as it gets!

Comment: @Daft - Well indeed :-)